# creating a url for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new to ROR, I, trying to update the field of a user from null to 1.
 I have written c controller for the same

```
def update_users
  Rails.logger.info("in Update users")
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.deleted=1    

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully Deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And Defined this in route as-

```
match '/update_users' => 'users#update_users', :as => 'update_users', :via => [:put]
```

my view for the same is-

```
= link_to raw('<span class="delete">Delete User</span>'), update_users_path(@user.id),
                                :method => :put,
                                :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' },
                                :remote =>true
```

But in the output i, getting /update_users.7 instead of /update_users/7.
and in the Network side I'm getting-

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#update_users

Couldn't find User without an ID
```

pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routing is incorrect - your new action should be a member action on your existing User routes.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions for more information.

Comment: Correct, please also keep in mind that when navigating to any id-specific resource (member) you should use the singular route variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your route to:

```
put '/update_users/:id' => 'users#update_users'
```

So that you can pass your ID to it properly. Then your link helper would be:

```
update_users_path(@user)
```

As it is now you haven't told the routes where to grab the ID from.

Comment: Wouldn't put '/update_users/:id' => 'users#update_users' be a more clean sollution?

Comment: but the problem is when im clicking on delete link the and checking development log, call to update_users is going many times. why this is happening.